# pom file java version spec for Maven

Tags: linux, java, amazon-ec2, compilation, maven

I am a new user to Maven, as I am trying to use it to build apache spark on amazon EC2 VMs. I have mannually installed java version 1.7.0 on the VMs. However as I was running the Maven, the following error occurs:

```
Failed to execute goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:testCompile (scala-test-compile-first) on project spark-core_2.10: Execution scala-test-compile-first of goal net.alchim31.maven:scala-maven-plugin:3.2.0:testCompile failed. CompileFailed
```

As I think the java version mismatch is the potential reason, causing the compiling problem. I opened up the pom file of the spark for maven tool, it has declared java related version in two seperate places:

```
<java.version>1.6</java.version>
```

and

```
<aws.java.sdk.version>1.8.3</aws.java.sdk.version>
```

What are the differences between these two versions? 
Which one should be edited to solve the jave version mismatch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's two different things

```
 <java.version>1.6</java.version>
```

is the java version used and

```
<aws.java.sdk.version>1.8.3</aws.java.sdk.version>
```

is the [AWS SDK for Java](http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/) version used.

The [minumum requirement of AWS SDK 1.9](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java#getting-started) is Java 1.6+ so there is no compatibility issues.

Comment: Is there any compatible issue with the two versions?

Comment: @bcxuezhe39 If you find my answer is the correct one, you can click on "accept this answer". If you find my answer is useful, you can upvote for it. It's a good practice to do this.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up! It's just I don't have enough privilages yet to vote up (requiring 15) since this account is relatively new